# Calling Julia via `ExternalEvaluate`

Tags: interoperability, julia

I am trying to call Julia from Mathematica via `ExternalEvaluate`, as per [this documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/ConfigureJuliaForExternalEvaluate.html) page.  I have Julia installed with all the required packages (`ZMQ`, `JSON`, and `LinearAlgebra`), but `FindExternalEvaluators["Julia"]` still cannot find Julia.  The documentation page has no further information.  How can I get Mathematica to find my Julia installation?  Perhaps it just doesn't know the right place to look?

Answer (score 3):

I solved my issue by making a link to the Julia executable in the directory `/usr/bin/`.  The link had to be named "Julia".

(For anyone trying to do this on a different OS, the way I identified this as the right location was to ask `FindExternalEvaluate` to look for Python instances--which it successfully found--and note the directory those were located in.)

Comment: What is your OS? (I had no problem hooking up to Julia from Mathematica on Mac OS 10.15.7.)

Comment: @AntonAntonov Linux Mint.